# Get Data Of Third Column Based on Two other Columns

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

This is a  sample table

```
ID  STOREA  STOREB  STOREC   AB   BC   CA  ABC
--- ------- ------  -------  --   --  ---  ---
10    1       0       0
10    0       1       0
10    0       1       0
29    0       1       0 
29    0       0       1
29    1       0       0
```

Each row corresponds to a purchase made at either of Store A or B or C. Customer 10 shops at A and B but not c. So I want `AB=1 BC=0 CA=0 ABC=0`  for all ID=10 rows and for ID=29, he shops at all 3, so I need `AB=1 BC=1 CA=1 ABC=1` for all rows where ID=29 (using ORACLE SQL)

I would like to update the columns in the table.

Comment: Can you normalize this table?

Comment: If you don't understand the comment by @PolishPrince, I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way you can do this.  I don't think you can use `JOINs` in Oracle with `UPDATE` statements -- however, you can accomplish the same thing by using `MERGE`:

```
MERGE
INTO    yourtable
USING   (
          select id as idnew, 
            case when a + b = 2 then 1 else 0 end abnew,
            case when b + c = 2 then 1 else 0 end bcnew,
            case when a + c = 2 then 1 else 0 end acnew,
            case when a + b + c = 3 then 1 else 0 end abcnew
          from (
            select 
              id,
              max(case storea when 1 then 1 else 0 end)  A,
              max(case storeb when 1 then 1 else 0 end)  B,
              max(case storec when 1 then 1 else 0 end)  C
            from yourtable
            group by id
          ) a
        )
ON      (id = idnew)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
SET     ab = abnew, 
  bc = bcnew,
  ac = acnew,
  abc = abcnew
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/326f7/1)

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Can you please tell me what are A,B,C and a,b,c and another 'a' after group by id.

Comment: @user2133404 -- all of those are aliases.  The little a after the group by is a table alias (needed when using subqueries).  The others are just column aliases where A is the same as a -- should have been more consistent.  Glad we could help!

Comment: Thanks a lot once again :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can do this as a `select`:

```
update (select id, storea, storeb, storec, AB as new_AB, BC as new_BC, AC as new_AC, ABC as new_ABC
        from t join
             (select id,
                     (case when max(storeA) = 1 and max(storeB) = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as AB,
                     (case when max(storeB) = 1 and max(storeC) = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as BC,
                     (case when max(storeA) = 1 and max(storeC) = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as AC,
                     (case when max(storeA) = 1 and max(storeB) = 1 and max(storeC) = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as ABC
              from t
              group by id
             ) tsum
             on t.id = tsum.id
            )
     set AB = new_AB, AC = new_AC, BC = new_BC, ABC = new_ABC;
```

I think this might work:

```
select id, storea, storeb, storec, AB, BC, AC, ABC
from t join
     (select id,
             (case when max(storeA) = 1 and max(storeB) = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as AB,
             (case when max(storeB) = 1 and max(storeC) = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as BC,
             (case when max(storeA) = 1 and max(storeC) = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as AC,
             (case when max(storeA) = 1 and max(storeB) = 1 and max(storeC) = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as ABC
      from t
      group by id
     ) tsum
     on t.id = tsum.id
            )
     set AB = new_AB, AC = new_AC, BC = new_BC, ABC = new_ABC;
```

Comment: Update queries can be written.  However, it's best to know what you are trying to do before trying to do it.  You've not explained that part very clearly.

Comment: I am trying to update the columns in the table, based on the customer ID and his store vists